# Problems with Search widget - ArcGIS API for Javascript

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I am new at this. I have cobbled together code from various examples. I am trying to create a map with a search widget and in which the popup info comes up in the bar at the bottom. I can't seem to do both.

When parser.parse() is commented out:
(1) the search widget appears, but doesn't have full functionality (no popup, no zoom).
(2) the popup information does not appear in the bottom bar

When parser.parse() isn't commented out, the search widget does not appear at all, but the popup information shows in the bottom bar when I click a feature.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Garbage and Recycling</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/esri/css/esri.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans">

<style>
    html, body {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        font-family: "Open Sans";
    }
    #search{
      display:block;
      background-color: white;
      position: absolute !important;
      top: 20px;
      right: 20px;
    }
    #container{
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        bottom:0;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        color: white;
        }
    #instructionDiv{
        font-style:italic;
        }
    #zoneDiv{
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-bottom:0;
        }
    #linkDiv{
        padding-top:0;
        }
    #garDiv{
       padding-bottom: 0;
       }
    #recDiv{
       padding-top:0;
       }
    #map {
        padding:0;
    }
    .nav {
        padding: 5px 10px;
        background: #4479BA;
        color: #FFF;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: solid 1px #20538D;
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
</style>

<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/"></script>
<script>
    require([
        "dojo/on",
        "dojo/_base/connect",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dijit/registry",
        "dojo/dom-construct",
        "dojo/parser",
        "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
        "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
        "esri/map",
        "esri/arcgis/utils",
        "esri/domUtils",
        "esri/dijit/Popup",
        "esri/dijit/Search"
        ],
    function(
        on,
        connect,
        dom,
        registry,
        domConstruct,
        parser,
        BorderContainer,
        ContentPane,
        Map,
        arcgisUtils,
        domUtils,
        Popup,
        Search
        )
    {
//parser.parse();
          //Create a map based on an ArcGIS Online web map id
          arcgisUtils.createMap("5cdc921a8e2d4eb08ab64a63d1c46e23", "map").then
            (function(response){
             var map = response.map;

              //set infoWindow to false
             map.infoWindow.set("popupWindow", false);

              initializeBottomBar(map);

              //create Search
              var search = new Search({map:map, enableInfoWindow: true, zoomScale: 1000}, "search");
              search.startup();
            });


             //initialize Bottom Bar (bottom)
             function initializeBottomBar(map){
               var popup = map.infoWindow;

               //when the selection changes, update the info bar
               connect.connect(popup, "onSelectionChange", function(){
                displayContent(popup.getSelectedFeature());
                });

               connect.connect(popup, "onSetFeatures", function(){
                 displayContent(popup.getSelectedFeature());
                 });
             }

             function displayContent(feature){
               if(feature){
                var content = feature.getContent();
                registry.byId("zoneDiv").set("content", content);
                }
              }

    });

</script>
</head>

<body class="claro">
      <div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
      </div>
      <div id="search" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"></div>
      <div id="container" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane">
        <div id="instructionDiv" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane">Click a collection zone on the map for more details.</div>
        <div id="zoneDiv" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"></div>
        <div id="linkDiv" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"></div>
        <div id="descDiv" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"></div>
        <div id="garDiv" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"></div>
        <div id="recDiv" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"></div>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

include this at the end of your require array

```
"dojo/domReady!"
```

no need to put a matching argument in the function though you can for completeness and to avoid issues when you inevitably add another module to require and forget to re-order the arguments so "dojo/domReady!" comes last.

EDIT:

additionally for any widget code you should include `"dojo/ready"` in the require array and then wrap the widget code in

`ready(function(){..widget code goes here...})`

See [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbXwLX?editors=101) for a working example

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34725993/246736) for more details